# Using Substring, within ISNULL in TSQL returns unexpected number of characters for the field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, isnull

My field in my SKU table

`(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5)` is `varchar(15)`

However below code returns just 3 characters `'Unc'` for the null fields in my table while it should return `'Uncategorized'`. How to solve that?

```
ISNULL(SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,3),'Uncategorized') AS phl1
```

Comment: Of course it returns just 3 characters, `ISNULL` takes two parameters, and returns the first, unless it is `NULL`, in which case it returns the second. So obviously, if `phl5` contains "Uncategorized", you'll return "Unc" since ISNULL will return the result of the substring. Please explain the logic behind what you want (not the code logic, the "thinking" logic, what you want and why)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen But phl5 does not contain "Uncategorized", What I am tring to do is that, when phl5 is not null, return the first 3 character, if it is null, return "Uncategorized", I tried this with the above code. However when it is null, the above code returns 'Unc'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,3) AS VARCHAR(13)),'Uncategorized') AS phl1
```

The size of the return type of SUBSTRING isn't clearly documented that I can find, but the problem is that the type of ISNULL is the type of the first expression, which is clearly coming back as VARCHAR(3) since you are truncating it to 3 characters.

[ISNULL docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CASE WHEN BI.dbo.SKU.phl5 IS NULL THEN 'Uncategorized' 
     ELSE SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,3) 
END AS phl1
```